# Google Calendar API -- "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to write some Python code that creates a calendar (within my own account) and adds events to it.

I keep on getting the following 403 error:

```
Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup
```

This does *not* happen when I create new calendars:

```
created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()
```

But the error *does* come up when I try and create events within the calendar I just made:

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId=created_calendar, body=event).execute()
```

As per other help threads, I've made all of the correct authentications (API key, OAuth, Service Account):

[image]

And my daily limit is way beyond the number of requests I've been sending:

[image]

I am specifying the OAuth credentials.json file when creating my api client. I am pointing the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable at the service account key (also json) before running.

I'm not sure how else I can authenticate myself...some help would really be appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is my script (and I believe a minimal example of the error) in case it's helpful:

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
# Add .readonly for read only
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']


def build_cal_service():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service

def main():
    service = build_cal_service()

    calendar = {
        'summary': 'TEST CAL',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    }

    created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()

    time = datetime.datetime(
        year=2019,
        month=11,
        day=9,
        hour=21,
        tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))

    event = {
      'summary': 'test summary',
      'description': 'test description.',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': time.isoformat(),
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': (time + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat(),
      },
      'attendees': [
        {'email': 'test1@example.com'},
        {'email': 'test2@example.com'},
      ],
    }

    event = service.events().insert(calendarId=created_calendar, body=event).execute()
```

Comment: So you're sure that you have got that credentials file in your working folder? Disable the public access to your calendar and try your program again. If it doesnt work you're not logged in.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation about `I am specifying the OAuth credentials.json file when creating my api client. I am pointing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable at the service account key (also json) before running.`, can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks lots for your suggestions!! No luck, unfortunately. 

Eirik Fesker -- I know it's picking up the credentials file and logging in because it is creating the "TEST CAL" calendar without any problems (only adding events to "TEST CAL" is an issue).

@Tanaike -- I've provided my script above.

Comment: Thank you for providing your script. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

Unfortunately, in my environment, when I tested your provided script, I couldn't confirm the error of `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup`. But I think that in your script, `event = service.events().insert(calendarId=created_calendar, body=event).execute()` occurs an error. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId=created_calendar, body=event).execute()
```

#### To:

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId=created_calendar['id'], body=event).execute()
```

#### Note:

- `created_calendar` of `created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()` is an object. So when the calendar ID is retrieved, please use `created_calendar['id']`.
- This answer supposes that `credentials.json` is the file which was downloaded by "Create credentials" at "OAuth client ID".
- **If the error related to the authorization occurs, please delete the file of `token.pickle` and run the script, and then authorize again.**

#### References:

- [Calendars: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)
- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: Tanaike, thank you so much. You are the greatest stackoverflow-er to walk these lands.

Comment: @Reid Pryzant Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.